# MySql remove rows which have duplicate column content

Tags: mysql

I get database table which contain postal numbers and regions for my country. That table have all information but i need to change it for my purpose.

I need to eliminate all rows that have duplicate content in specific column.

**Check screenshot to see result**
[image]

I want to remove all duplicate rows which have **postanski_broj** (postal_number) the some. That number need to be unique. I try manualy to set that column to unique but i get duplicate entry when i try to execute statment.

- ID is primary key with auto increment.
- postanski_broj column is VARCHAR which represent postal_code
- naselje column is VARCHAR which represent region

One region can have one postal_code

**I try**

```
ALTER  TABLE poste ADD UNIQUE INDEX idx_postanski_br (postanski_broj);
```

> 00:03:20  ALTER  TABLE poste ADD UNIQUE INDEX idx_postanski_br
> (postanski_broj)  Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry '11158' for key
> 'idx_postanski_br'    0.118 sec

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE poste ADD UNIQUE INDEX idx_postanski_br (postanski_broj);
```

> 00:04:17  ALTER IGNORE TABLE poste ADD UNIQUE INDEX idx_postanski_br
> (postanski_broj)  Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL
> syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
> for the right syntax to use near 'IGNORE TABLE poste ADD UNIQUE INDEX
> idx_postanski_br (postanski_broj)' at line 1  0.00037 sec

Anyone have sugestion? Thanks

Comment: Please provide your data and code as text rather than images.

Comment: Thanks for vote down! I put image like result output and example code what i try as text. I cant put visual result as text.

Comment: Why are you trying `ALTER` instead of `DELETE`? I mean, you are trying to ALTER your table to set a new constraint (unique), I got it, but that must be done after deleting the rows.

Comment: My plain is to add uniqe and i thinked that unique will eliminate duplicate. Let me try with delete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have other columns with different values than the ones you've shown there (except for `id`), deleting should be your last choice.

I usually would duplicate the table first:

```
CREATE TABLE poste_new LIKE poste;
```

add unique index to the newly created `poste_new` table:

```
ALTER  TABLE poste_new ADD UNIQUE INDEX idx_postanski_br (postanski_broj);
```

insert the data from `poste` into `poste_new` with `IGNORE` option to skip duplicates based on the unique index:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO poste_new SELECT * FROM poste;
```

rename the tables:

```
RENAME TABLE poste TO poste_old;
RENAME TABLE poste_new TO poste;
```

The good thing about this is that you've minimized the risk of wrong delete and if you're not satisfied with the new table, you still have the old table intact - effectively making it a backup.

Comment: I cant use IGNORE i put in question Mysql Workbench dont allow.

Comment: That's `ALTER IGNORE`.. the one I suggest is `INSERT IGNORE`

Comment: let me test this code

Comment: 1484 row(s) affected, 64 warning(s): 1062 Duplicate entry '11158' for key 'idx_postanski_br' 1062 Duplicate entry '11158' ..... I do first like you say to create after update and then when i try to insert i get this

Comment: Yes, now you can check the new table and see if there are duplicates.

Comment: I can tell you thanks for time this is good way to not lost data and fix problem. Now work. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

> **This solution can take too much time for big tables. Best way of solving this is: [Remove duplicate rows in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311903/remove-duplicate-rows-in-mysql/47392593#47392593)**

You have to delete the rows before applying the unique constraint. Be careful applying this:

```
DELETE p1 FROM poste p1
INNER JOIN poste p2 
WHERE 
    p1.id < p2.id AND 
    p1.postanski_broj = p2.postanski_broj;
```

This should remove the duplicated ones and will keep only the ones with the higher id (id=168044 in your example).